# unable to pull public images with kubernetes using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, dockerhub, kubectl

I run the following commands and when I check if the pods are running I get the following errors:

> Failed to pull image "tomcat": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = no
>   matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries

```
kubectl run tomcat --image=tomcat --port 8080
```

and

> Failed to pull image "ngnix": rpc error: code = Unknown desc
>   = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ngnix, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

```
kubectl run nginx3 --image ngnix --port 80
```

I seen a post in git about how to complete this when private repos cause an issue but not public. Has anyone ran into this before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First Problem**

From github [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/3835)

> Sometimes, we'll have non-amd64 image build jobs finish before their amd64 counterparts, and due to the way we push the manifest list objects to the library namespace on the Docker Hub, that results in amd64-using folks (our primary target users) getting errors of the form "no supported platform found in manifest list" or "no matching manifest for XXX in the manifest list entries"

Docker Hub manifest list is not up-to-date with `amd64` build for `tomcat:latest`.

Try another tag

```
kubectl run tomcat --image=tomcat:9.0 --port 8080
```

**Second Problem**

Use `nginx` not `ngnix`. *Its a typo*.

```
$ kubectl run nginx3 --image nginx --port 80
```

Comment: This is exactly the mistake I did. ngnix instead of nginx. thank u

Comment: typo  ! how I missed !